# Set an image to fill the canvas using Paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have an image that has the same aspect ratio as the canvas but a different resolution. I know I can make use of the view size, `view.viewSize`, but my trouble is setting the dimensions of the image. I have tried setting the width using `raster.width = 2000;`, for example, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working for me.

```
raster.size = paper.view.viewSize;
raster.position = paper.view.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **raster.bounds** instead

(for width)

```
raster.bounds.width = 2000;
```

or

(for height)

```
raster.bounds.height = 2000;
```

So, you right, you should be able to get canvas size with:

```
paper.view.viewSize
```

and assign the raster the proper with/height